# What defines default colors for highlight groups not present in a color scheme?

Tags: colorscheme, default-settings

After updating to vim 9.1 yesterday, diff highlighting colors were broken for me. Comparing with an older vim (7.4) on a different machine, it seems that the cause was probably a change in the diff.vim syntax file using DiffAdd/Delete/Change as the relevant highlighting groups instead of Identifier/Special/PreProc like previously; thus I fixed this by adding the appropriate `hi` entries to my color scheme. But during the investigation, I could not figure out how the default colors for those hl groups are determined.

For example, here are the values for `DiffDelete` as given by `:echo hlget('DiffDelete')` before adding a `hi DiffDelete` entry to my scheme:

```
[{'id': 30, 'ctermfg': '12', 'name': 'DiffDelete', 'gui': {'bold': v:true},
'term': {'bold': v:true}, 'ctermbg': '6', 'guibg': 'DarkCyan', 'guifg': 'Blue'}]
```

Also, vim used the `guifg/bg` values instead of the `ctermfg/bg` values, as `ctermfg=12` should be red but deleted lines were highlighted blue on cyan.

Example:

[image: example].

I checked the following places for highlighting definitions and related config:

- The default color scheme under `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/default.vim` is basically empty and does not define any relevant colors.
- My existing color scheme (based on mustang) did not define them either.
- Other color schemes in `$VIMRUNTIME/colors` definie `DiffDelete` highlights, but no scheme matches even one of the fg/bg values.

I'm setting `t_Co=256` in my vimrc and `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`; I don't think any other vimrc settings are relevant.

So in summary, here's my questions:

- Are the default color values such as the hlget output above hardcoded somewhere in the vim code? If not, is it in some configuration file outside of `$VIMRUNTIME`, or is it dynamically determined based on the env / terminal / whatever?
- Why does the default highlighting above result in the `guibg/fg` being applied instead of the `ctermbg/fg` values - shouldn't the gui values only be used in gvim etc and not in a terminal?

Comment: What version did you have prior? Can you try building that (or checking it out) and comparing?

Comment: fyi: I documented it here: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b1392bee701d887b66b596c9af26bfcb6f0614b8

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm on arch linux and had `vim-9.0.2167` previously. Highlighting looks as expected when reverting to that version and removing the `hi Diff*` lines in my colorscheme. The `hlget('DiffDelete')` output is identical, but it's not yet relevant in that version as can be seen in the doc linked by Christian.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thanks, that explains that my analysis of the cause was correct. However, it does not explain what causes the wonky default highlighting for those hl groups.

Comment: @romainl I added an example image

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt what is the rationale behind that decision? `DiffAdd` and friends are used in a very different context from `DiffAdded` and friends. So that makes no sense to me. The former is for side-by-side diffs, where areas have a background and so on, while the latter is for when you open a diff **file**, where having those background colors would be an abomination.

Comment: @l4mpi thanks, I figured out what the problem was in the mean time. That commit should be reverted ASAP.

Comment: See the linked issues

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here is the content of a `diff` file *without* the change mentioned by Christian in the comments:

[image: before]

Obviously, the exact colors depend on the colorscheme, but it certainly is meaningful and readable.

Now, here is how the same file looks after the change in question:

[image: after]

This is way too noisy.

Comment: Fixed as of [v9.1.0016](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v9.1.0016)

Answer (score 1):

> Are the default color values such as the hlget output above hardcoded somewhere in the vim code?

Yes, the defaults are hardcoded in C source. Except, named color constants are defined in VimScript runtime (in late builds). That would be a shame if Vim crashed on startup if one had erased VIMRUNTIME folder, wouldn't it?

> Why does the default highlighting above result in the guibg/fg being applied instead of the ctermbg/fg values

This depends on `:h 'termguicolors'` option setting. It is off by default, so blame your config. However, many popular color schemes do not provide any reasonable values for 256 color palette, and almost all terminal programs have support for TrueColor anyway. So everyone types `set termguicolors` into personal vimrc, and only few bother about its meaning.

Comment: `set termguicolors?` shows `notermguicolors`, so apparently it's off in my config, and turning it on changes lots of colors. So I think it has to be something else. The only related setting in my rather minimal .vimrc is `t_Co=256` and potentially `nocompatible` (not sure if it does anything here but `:h termguicolors` mentions "This option is reset when 'compatible' is set").

Comment: @l4mpi Don't set t_Co manually, as it's set from TERM. And never touch compatible option for any version built in the current millenium. termguicolors is the only option that forces terminal vim into 24-bit color mode. If you claim otherwise then you are just wrong.

Comment: I'm not claiming anything about 24 bit modes. I'm just stating a fact; my vimrc results in `notermguicolors` (and I just confirmed that it has no relevant settings by removing everything but `syntax on` and `colorscheme $name` - same behaviour). You are the one claiming that the guifg/bg is applied due to `termguicolors` and I'm saying that is not the issue in my case as it's not set. Maybe I'm missing something else entirely, but to my understanding the default `ctermfg/bg` values for DiffDelete should result in red on yellow, and as you can see in my screenshot I get blue on cyan instead.

Comment: @l4mpi You are one who wrote in your question literally "vim used the guifg/bg values instead of the ctermfg/bg values". And guifg/bg are 24-bit long. Now you say you didn't say anything about 24-bit... So don't be surprised if you are not understood.

Comment: That is how I interpreted the visuals I get (as shown in the screenshot) in combination with the `hlget('DiffDelete')` output. I apologize if that was incorrect and caused confision, however how else would you interpret that data?

Comment: @l4mpi MCVE = minimal complete and verifiable example. There is no one here who knows what you did last summer.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, I already verified this with a 2-line vimrc. I just now confirmed it with a minimal colorscheme as well. So MCVE is, use vim 9.1, create a "test.vim" colorscheme with the following content: `set background=dark \n hi clear \n let colors_name = "test" \n hi Normal ctermfg=254 ctermbg=234`, use the following .vimrc: `colorscheme test \n syntax on` (replace "\n" with newlines). Note that some lines of the diff file will look different than in the screenshot, e.g. the "@@" line is yellow, but the add/delete lines still look the same on my end (blue/cyan).

Comment: The colorscheme can even be further simplified, the `hi clear` line is not needed. Without it all other text will be white on black but the wonky diff highlighting is unchanged.